# If my question's accepted answer is no longer the best, should I change the accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

2 years ago I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22660778/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-default-points-of-interest-from-android-google-map).

At that time someone answered my question stating that "what I am requesting is not possible" and provided a link to an "request" made to Google to add this feature.

Two years later, another answer was added, stating that this feature is available now and doable.

Should I change the selection of the best answer and choose the new answer?
Because if I leave it as is, it might be misleading. On the other hand, if I change it, it might be unfair to the original person who answered my question correctly at that time.

Comment: A very good question. Concerning the rep points, I don't think MaciejGórski  will loose any sleep over them. However, both answers need a **date** added, or else people may favor the highest voted answer over the most recent.

Comment: But not a duplicate question. The discussion from the related question pertains to writing a self answer and accepting it down the road as a solution in hindsight. This discussion focuses on other users posting an answer down the road and what options exist at that point. I have reopened this question as a result.

Comment: A weird definition of "fair". You would leave an incorrect answer as the accepted one in the interest of "fairness"? What about fairness to the people looking for the right answer?

Comment: IMO you can accept the answer or upvote the new answer it will still help the new user to understand the importance of new answer.

Comment: StackOverflow is a vehicle for capturing best answers to questions, it is not a vehicle for distributing brownie points to users. Do what is right for readers of the site, brownie points should fall out as a side-effect.

Comment: Yes please. Waiting to delete one of the points from my profile summary.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62252/is-it-poor-form-to-switch-accepted-answers

Answer (score 142, accepted):

From the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) (emphasis mine):

> Accepting an answer is **not** meant to be a **definitive** and **final** statement indicating that the question has now been answered perfectly.

So, while at the time of posting, the answer (it's not possible with the current version of the API) was perfect, it has now been superseded by a new one, and you are encouraged to accept the new answer.

Comment: If you think the original one becomes misleading, change the accepted answer as you please!

Comment: you could also write a comment on the previously accepted answer stating why you unaccept it, so there is no confusion

Comment: @slawekwin in this case, it's pretty obvious why the new answer has been accepted.

Answer (score 54):

> On the other hand, if I change it, it might be unfair to the original person who answered my question correctly at that time

You shouldn't worry about that. Over a long life answering questions at Stack Overflow, I've learned to take it in stride when my answer, which was accepted at the time, gets unaccepted. The OP has a *perfect right to do this*, and it's my job to be mature and calm and accept that fact. It happens now and then, and I just have to shrug it off. Much of the time, I'm actually in favor of what the OP did; I say, "Yes, that newly accepted answer really *is* better than mine was."

So it's your job as the OP to accept whatever is currently the best answer. Do not worry about the "feelings" of the original answerer. What you're doing is not "unfair".

Comment: Another way of looking at this is that fairness to the hundreds of people who are going to find your question and read the "accepted" answer outweighs fairness to one single user.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Well put.

Answer (score 15):

This question highlights the main controversy of Stack Overflow.

All the participants are totally concerned about particular Opening Poster's problem only.

While the mission of the site is to serve much more people than just person who happened to ask the question. But for some reason only few ever taking into account the future life of their contribution. For example, you very seldom see an answer edited to make it meet the modern demands. Or very few make their answer applicable to a wider, more general solution.

Yet, if you think of it, beside the Opening Poster, there are hundreds of visitors from Google. Seven hundred in your case, as opposite to three persons involved personally - you and two answers' authors.

So if you are concerned of your question's value for the community, the answer is obvious - of course the best answer should be shown first.

But it's no harm to take personal feelings into account either. After all SO is about big numbers. There are other answers to your question, and which one will be picked by Google is a lottery. Yet the participants' feelings is the main concern of SO staff - everyone should be cheerful and happy. So you can choose the answer that makes you more happy - it will be all right as well.

Comment: ... except that Opening Poster is not really the definition we use for OP.