# Is it OK to ask a person to accept a different answer because it is more up to date than the current one?

Tags: discussion, comments

While searching the web for something I came across this question:
*[About changing glyphicon font colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379153/can-i-add-color-to-bootstrap-icons-only-using-css)*

I noticed that the first answer has a lot of votes compared to the other answers, yet the second answer is more up to date than the original one.

I know that the person who asked the question will have gotten a notification that a new answer was added to his or her question and that the choice lies with that person whether to accept it or not as new answer.

But is it OK to write a comment on the question that there is a more practical answer available other than the accepted answer?
To inform both the person who asked the question as well as other people searching for a solution/information?

Comment: I think you are trying the wrong solution for a real problem. Once we stop treating the accepted answer as special and not pin it on top, this will go away.

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335658/if-my-questions-accepted-answer-is-no-longer-the-best-should-i-change-the-acce

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is OK (and frankly a good thing) to leave a comment saying why one answer is better than the other. You could leave it on the answer which is *old / not up to date*. This way, hopefully, the people looking at the old answer will know what they are dealing with. Also note that, you can do the same thing with answers that work as expected but have some other issues / drawbacks. try not to be harsh (we don't want people DVing old answers just because they are not up-to-date)

Comment: "we don't want people DVing old answers just because they are not up-to-date" actually, we want them, these answer are not useful, which the downvote button clearly state.

Comment: @Braiam - So, are you saying that each time you see a Java 1.4 answer (which doesn't use generics) to answer a question, you plan on down-voting it?. Same applies to use of "deprecated methods". There is no need to Up vote such answers but at one particular point of time, they were right. A comment would do the trick IMO. A comment like - *This only applies to version X (which is old), do not use it for versions beyond X*

Comment: We are talking about obsolete answers... obsolete answers by definition *are not useful to anyone*, they are obsolete, unusable in its current form. And obviously we want the best answers to rise to the top downvotes help with that. If downvotes motivate the OP to fix them up or delete them, bless them. Recommended read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265769/792066 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261817/213575

Comment: Oh, btw, important information like obsoletence of the solution should result in post edition, since comments can be removed any time for any reason, so we want that information in the post itself.

Comment: @Braiam - Well, if those answers suggest downvoting *obsolete* answers, I disagree. Also, a comment that states that an answer is obsolete (or points out problems with it) is *constructive* . It shouldn't be deleted. Moving that comment to the answer isn't a bad idea (but then again we are still running the risk of people editing it out). It is easier to edit an answer to *remove* that content but difficult to delete a comment on an answer.  I personally would leave a comment (that's what I do with valid answers that can cause problems in a particular situation)

Comment: @Braiam But when is an answer about code obsolete? So much software runs on old versions... Also, the question i added as an example, the accepted answer is not obsolete, it can probably still be used, the follow up answer is simply better and has a code example. but the difference in votes is nearly 10x.

Comment: @Vahx "the follow up answer is simply better" and should be on top, just for that reason. Remember, the best answer rise to the top as result of our voting, why would we  want the answer on the top not being the "best"?

Comment: @HansPassant yes, it took me a while to discover it. I recommend you to do the same, I find my time on SO much more productive when I answer questions that can be answered *as is*.

Comment: @Braiam I understand how voting works, but when a new answer only has 19 votes and the accepted answer has 170+, you know that voting will take a lot of time to reach its goal. But if the new answer becomes the accepted answer, it will just be at the top.

Answer (score 0):

In a ideal world, the top answer should be the answer that will solve the question all the times. In our world, the top answer *should be* that that solves the question the 90% of the times, as it's very likely that most people will use this one first, will assure us that most people that search are satisfied with the results and therefore it reinforces the conduct of ["searching before asking"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/792066) which is a Good Thing™ for obvious reasons.

I think, that the most sensible solution to the problem you perceive is that we treat the accepted answer as nothing more than a signal that this answer solved OP issue and nothing else, and let community decide which answer solves the 90% of the cases by normal voting. Basically, once we stop pinning the accepted answer to the top, you can expect that in the long run, the community will sort out the answers that best solves the question and is flexible enough to respond to externalities.

Now, that's my ideal solution, another would be to include addenda or update the accepted answer as time passes.