# Should I change the accepted answer if a new answer answers the question better?

Tags: discussion, answers, accepted-answer

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29668164/using-sql-calc-found-rows-within-a-sqldataprovider-in-yii2/40660923) over a year ago now and accepted a [workable solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29734330/472501) that I am still happy with, however it didn't *specifically* solve the question that I asked how to do, but solved it in an acceptable manner to me.

Now someone else has come in and [answered the question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40660923/472501) and posted a solution that more specifically does what I asked how to do, however I have chosen to remain using the original accepted answer as I am still happy with it (at least for the time being) - on top of that I haven't even tested the new answer to see if it works how I would want it to, so whilst it *appears* like it fits the purpose, I haven't actually tested it myself.

So, should I leave the currently accepted answer or accept the new one that more specifically answers the original question?

Comment: It's (in essence) the same as [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335658/if-my-questions-accepted-answer-is-no-longer-the-best-should-i-change-the-acce) - yes, it's acceptable and even recommended.

Comment: Does this imply that it is expected behavior to periodically plow through the answers your questions have received to see if a better one has shown up in the meanwhile?

Comment: @JohnHascall you get a notification in your inbox every time you receive a new answer to your question. It doesn't hurt to look, you don't need to go over all your questions once in a while.

Comment: @Glorfindel I was already aware of that question you pointed to, but I felt my question was different seeing as I will not be using the new answers solution (at least for now) and I also haven't even tested it as stated in my post.

Comment: I wouldn't accept an answer that I haven't tested, and I wouldn't feel obliged to go back and test an answer on a year old question. If it's good quality give it an upvote. Other people who come across your question because they had the same problem will take care of the rest and if the new one is better it will eventually gather more votes.

Comment: Good advice @ivarni